# how to call a asp.net webservice in android using phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a asp.net web service accessing value from database using a datatable
and my javascript goes like this in eclipse where it is running in android simulator using phonegap but this code seems not to be working .pls help me out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function GetAge() {
         jQuery.support.cors = true;
          $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
           $.ajax({
          data: datas, 
             type: "POST",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",   
             url: "http://localhost:50113/Service1.asmx/mydbCon?wsdl",
             success: function (msg) {
                $('#divToBeWorkedOn').html(msg.text); 
             },
             error: function (e) {
                 $('#divToBeWorkedOn').html("unavailable");
             }
         });
     } 
  </script>
```

and my service1.asmx goes like this

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public DataTable mydbCon()
    {
        SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection("");
        SqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand SqlComm = new SqlCommand();
        SqlComm.Connection = SqlCon;
        SqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlComm.CommandText = "select password from tbl_login where username='aby';";
        DataTable EmployeeDt = new DataTable("tbl_login");
        SqlDataAdapter SqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlComm);
        SqlDa.Fill(EmployeeDt);
        return EmployeeDt;
    }
```

Comment: is mydbCon the method name in the service1.asmx? can you show the content of service1.asmx?

Comment: i Have added my service1.asmx check it out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2979938/169714 and why do you use `?wsdl`?

Comment: i have deleted the >wsdl and checked also but not working

Comment: because you just return a datatable instead of json, please use http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: ok thanx is there any other method that I can use right away itself

Comment: can you call the webserce using java code?

Answer (score 3):

Add Json.Net to your solution with the [package manager console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console) or by the [dialog](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/managing-nuget-packages-using-the-dialog)

and then:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string mydbCon()
{
    SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection("");
    SqlCon.Open();
    SqlCommand SqlComm = new SqlCommand();
    SqlComm.Connection = SqlCon;
    SqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlComm.CommandText = "select password from tbl_login where username='aby';";
    DataTable EmployeeDt = new DataTable("tbl_login");
    SqlDataAdapter SqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlComm);
    SqlDa.Fill(EmployeeDt);
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(EmployeeDt, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

Here is the link of Json.Net on the nuget gallery: http://nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: hey thanks for the code but i cant insdtall json.net in visual studio express 2010 since I dont have the option library package manager .Let me ask my admin to install VS ultimatum and try this out any way thanks a lot

Comment: or download the dll, put it in your bin folder and reference it

Comment: or open your solution in visual web developer express http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566908/how-can-i-use-nuget-with-visual-c-sharp-express do you have nuget installed? http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c